# Overloadable boost::asio::basic_stream_socket

Tags: c++, templates, boost-asio, generic-programming

Developing a network application, I have a Connection class that manages sending and receiving messages on the network. I'm using boost::asio.

I now want to let the Connection class handle connections both over TCP, and over local UNIX stream sockets. However, the template-design of boost confuses me. AFAICT, there's no shared base-class between local::stream_protocol::socket and ip::tcp::socket.

How would I go about creating a Connection that encapsulates the network-semantics such that other code don't have to deal with the details of what protocol is used?

I.E. I want to implemented something like:

```
class Connection() {
  Connection(ip::tcp::endpoint& ep);
  Connection(local::stream_protocol::endpoint& ep);

  void send(Buffer& buf);
}
```

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some pondering, my current solution is to make the send and recv functions of `Connection` virtual, and create a template-subclass of `Connection`, roughly:

```
template <typename Protocol>
class ConnectionImpl : public Connection {
    typedef typename Protocol::socket Socket;
    typedef typename Protocol::endpoint EndPoint;

    Socket _socket;
public:
    ConnectionImpl(boost::asio::io_service& ioSvc, const EndPoint& addr) 
        : Connection(ioSvc), _socket(ioSvc) { 
        _socket.connect(addr);
    }

    void trySend() {
        // Initiate async send on _socket here
    }

    void tryRead() {
        // Initiate async recv on _socket here
    }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the need to subclass and use of virtual functions?

Answer (score 1):

> AFAICT, there's no shared base-class between
>   local::stream_protocol::socket and ip::tcp::socket.

There is explicitly no base class for all socket objects on purpose, the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/networking/bsd_sockets.html) describes the rationale quite well

> Unsafe and error prone aspects of the BSD socket API not included. For
>   example, the use of int to represent all sockets lacks type safety.
>   The socket representation in Boost.Asio uses a distinct type for each
>   protocol, e.g. for TCP one would use ip::tcp::socket, and for UDP one
>   uses ip::udp::socket

Comment: Thank you for the links doc. I had missed that.

That said, it's a bit limiting that boost does not support shared interface for compatible sockets. I.E. a stream-type UNIX socket has VERY compatible semantics with a TCP-socket, so sharing a base-class with possibly one or two virtual functions would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use boost::asio:generic::stream_protocol::socket instead. When you call async_connect()/connect(), it will extract the family and protocol from the remote endpoint and then pass them to the socket() syscall to create the correct socket.

```
boost::asio::generic::stream_protocol::socket socket_{io_service};

if (use_unix_socket) {
    boost::asio::local::stream_protocol::endpoint unix_endpoint{"/tmp/socketpath.sock"};
    socket_.async_connect(unix_endpoint, [](boost::system::error_code ec){

    }};
}
else {
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint tcp_endpoint{...};
    socket_.async_connect(tcp_endpoint, [](boost::system::error_code ec){

    }};
}
```

And there is the code from boost::asio::basic_socket:

```
template <typename ConnectHandler>
  BOOST_ASIO_INITFN_RESULT_TYPE(ConnectHandler,
      void (boost::system::error_code))
  async_connect(const endpoint_type& peer_endpoint,
      BOOST_ASIO_MOVE_ARG(ConnectHandler) handler)
  {
    // If you get an error on the following line it means that your handler does
    // not meet the documented type requirements for a ConnectHandler.
    BOOST_ASIO_CONNECT_HANDLER_CHECK(ConnectHandler, handler) type_check;

    if (!is_open())
    {
      boost::system::error_code ec;
      const protocol_type protocol = peer_endpoint.protocol();
      if (this->get_service().open(this->get_implementation(), protocol, ec))
      {
        detail::async_result_init<
          ConnectHandler, void (boost::system::error_code)> init(
            BOOST_ASIO_MOVE_CAST(ConnectHandler)(handler));

        this->get_io_service().post(
            boost::asio::detail::bind_handler(
              BOOST_ASIO_MOVE_CAST(BOOST_ASIO_HANDLER_TYPE(
                ConnectHandler, void (boost::system::error_code)))(
                  init.handler), ec));

        return init.result.get();
      }
    }

    return this->get_service().async_connect(this->get_implementation(),
        peer_endpoint, BOOST_ASIO_MOVE_CAST(ConnectHandler)(handler));
  }
```